# TypeError: Cannot read property startsWith of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

import AttributeDescription from './AttributeDescription';

class CompEntry extends React.Component{

render(){

    let description;

    if(this.props.description.startsWith("_")){
        description= this.props.description.slice(1, this.props.description.length);
    }
    if(this.props.description.startsWith("__")){
        description = this.props.description.slice(2, this.props.description.length);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                <AttributeDescription description={description}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
}
export default CompEntry;
```

The mentioned error happened if I do the stuffs before the return. However, if i dont do anything before the `return` and just pass `this props.description` into the `description prop` of the `<AttributeDescription/>` tag, everything works fine, a defined props is passed into the tag. It seems like if the value of `this.props.description` does not exist if i try to access its property. Anyone knows why?

This is how I use the `CompEntry` component above:

```
import React from 'react';
import CompEntry from './CompEntry';
import CompHeading from './CompHeading';

class CompTable extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        products: [],
        attributes: [],
        attDesc: [],
    };
    this.getEntries = this.getEntries.bind(this);
}

getEntries = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/hello/data');
    const body = response.json();
    return body;
};

componentDidMount(){
    this.getEntries()
        .then((resolve) => this.setState({
            products: resolve.products, 
            attributes: resolve.attributes, 
            attDesc: resolve.attributesDescription}))
        .catch(err=>console.log(err));
};


render(){
    console.log(this.state.products);
    let highlightEntry= true;
    let compEntries = this.state.attributes.map( (item, index) =>{
       highlightEntry = !highlightEntry; 

       return(
           <CompEntry key={index} attribute={item} description={this.state.attDesc[index]} comparees={this.state.products} color={highlightEntry}/>            
       );
    });

    return(
        <div id = "comp-table">
            <div id="comp-sub-container">   
                <CompHeading comparees={this.state.products}/> 
                {compEntries}
            </div>
        </div>  
    );
}


}

export default CompTable;
```

Comment: `console.log` your `this.props.description` variable. The only way this error will appear is if it has no value. The reason everything works fine in your other case is because you are not trying to access a method on the string which ends up being `undefined`. Can you include the code where you are rendering this CompEntry component?

Comment: Try accessing props under constructor function with super(props)

Comment: Can you show, how you use the component?

Comment: @awarrier99 I put `console.log(this.props.description)` just after the opening of `render` and it still does not solve the problem.

Comment: @kabison33 it is not meant to solve your problem, I suggested doing that so you can see what the value of the variable is in order to _debug_ your problem

Comment: @Domino987 I edited my post to show how I used the component..

Comment: @awarrier Hey, i did `console.log` and it shows string in the console (as i expected). Though, the problem is gone when I put `let description = String(this.props.description);` and use `.startsWith` on this `description` variable. Does that mean that the string logged to the console is an undefined object/not an actual string? The value of `this.props.description` is from a database query btw.

Comment: Can you show the exact output of  `console.log(this.props.description)`? But yeah, doing `String(this.props.description)` will produce a string even if `this.props.description` is `undefined`, which is why it doesn't cause the error. For some reason your `this.props.description` variable is `undefined`

Comment: Also you should be doing `await response.json()` in your `getEntries` function, rather than just `response.json()`, that could be part of the problem. You're setting the description prop as `this.state.attDesc[index]` so this value is more than likely `undefined`, causing the error when you try to use the prop in the CompEntry component

Answer (score -1):

Edit: As mentioned by @awarrier99 in the comments, the `response.json()` function returns a Promise so you need to handle that appropriately. The code below has been updated for that also.

You do not set `description` to anything if the leading character is not an underscore.  Also if it starts with two underscores, it also starts with one underscore so that can double the work. I recommend doing this:

```
render(){
  let description = this.props.description;

  if (description.startsWith("__")) {
    description = description.slice(2, description.length);
  } else if (description.startsWith("_")) {
    description= description.slice(1, description.length);
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <div>
        <AttributeDescription description={description}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
}
```

This way if `this.props.description` does not start with any underscores it will still send that value, and the `slice` only gets done once if there are underscores. The code also gets easier to read by using the simpler `description` variable instead of `this.props.description` being repeated throughout.

Update your `getEntries` function to return the Promise given by the `json()` function. You could also `await` on it, but since `getEntries` is `async` it's already returning a Promise so this is simplest.

```
getEntries = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/hello/data');
    return response.json(); // return the Promise
};
```